# Text align in Illustrator CS5

Tags: text, adobe-illustrator

I want to know how I can align text in Illustrator CS5

I've created a logo and I want the text above the logo to have the same with as the logo, but I don't want the text to become deformed.

So what I want is::

```
T   E   S   T
LOGOLOGOLOGOL
```

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a text field, you can set its adjustment to "justify (all characters)" (you have to expand the paragraph panel for that, it's the most right adjustment). Then the text you enter is automatically distributed.

Otherwise, you can also emulate that behaviour in one of these two ways:

1. You can either change the distance between the character manually by increasing the tracking in the character panel (I don't know its correct english name); it's the control with the "A V" and the arrow below.
2. Or you can split the text field into one for each character and distribute that equally using the align panel.

Comment: `it's the control with the "A V" and the arrow below.` I believe it's called `Kerning`

Comment: It’s actually really tracking (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_%28typography%29), Kerning is the other button with the “A V”.